# Replace double-quote within a value attribute of an xml file in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, import, replace, export

I have the following node in my xml file which is an export of another program. 
I'll have to edit the xml file within my application so I can import it on a proper way.

The node:

```
<field name="memo" value="24-06-2004 Lorem ipsum dolor "sit" amit"/>
```

Eventually it has to become something like this

```
<field name="memo" value="24-06-2004 Lorem ipsum dolor &quot;sit&quot; amit"/>
```

Or

```
<field name="memo" value="24-06-2004 Lorem ipsum dolor 'sit' amit"/>
```

Comment: Can't you fix the program that's producing invalid XML?

Comment: That program isn't mine. Sadly i can't change anything about it.

Comment: Can you be absolutely sure that that invalid XML at least has all the quotes (even the ones you want replaced) correctly balanced, and that there are no `>` characters anywhere inside any of the attributes, and that there are no comments or CDATA sections anywhere that might contain quotes?

Comment: I could verify that, there is no CDATA at all. The whole xml is build the same way as above, all field with an name and value. the `>` is also never used anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, _
    "(?<=         # Assert that this matches before the current position:" & chr(10) & _
    " ^           # Start of string                                      " & chr(10) & _
    " [^""]*""    # Match any number of non-quotes, then one quote       " & chr(10) & _
    " (?>[^""]*"" # Match pairs of quotes,                               " & chr(10) & _
    "    [^""]*"" # optional non-quotes in-between                       " & chr(10) & _
    " )*          # any number of times.                                 " & chr(10) & _
    " [^""]*      # Match any number of non-quotes                       " & chr(10) & _
    ")            # End of lookbehind assertion                          " & chr(10) & _
    """           # MATCH ONE QUOTE                                      " & chr(10) & _
    "(?!          # Assert that the following cannot match here:         " & chr(10) & _
    " \s+         #  Whitespace                                          " & chr(10) & _
    " \w+=        #  An identifier like value=                           " & chr(10) & _
    "|            # or                                                   " & chr(10) & _
    " \s*         #  optional whitespace                                 " & chr(10) & _
    " [/?]?       #  followed by either / or ? or nothing                " & chr(10) & _
    " >           #  followed by >                                       " & chr(10) & _
    ")            # End of lookahead assertion.                          " & chr(10) & _
    "|            # OR do the same in the other direction:               " & chr(10) & _
    "(?<!\w+=)""(?=[^""]*""(?>[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)", _
    "&quot;", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

Comment: It seems to be working almost. The first line of the xml is also edited `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1&quot;?>`. The rest seems to be ok.

Comment: @R.Schaaphuizen: OK, I added this case to the regex and commented it.

Comment: ?: Thanks, this is working. I've changed the regex regarding to your edit so I have it without the comments. It is working now :)